# Change vim colorscheme on school's server

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-14.04

I have created my own colorscheme, and would like to set it as my default in my ~/.vimrc file.

My problem being, (as I understand it), I am on my school's linux server (Ubuntu 14.04), where many hundreds of students have accounts. 
I have read into this, and as I see it, I cannot change the colorscheme because the directory that vim is searching through is /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/, which I do not have access to.

How might I go about adding my colorscheme as default for my acount?
Perhaps editing the ~/.vimrc file to search for a file within my home directory (~/.vim/colors/scheme.vim)? I have tried that, but could not make any progress.

Am I out of luck on this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have `let g:colors_name = "scheme"` in your ~/.vim/colors/scheme.vim and then run `:colorscheme scheme` .

Answer (score 3):

The standard location is:

```
~/.vim/colors/colorschemename.vim
```

and you call it in your `~/.vimrc` like this:

```
colorscheme colorschemename
```

***NEVER*** do anything in `/usr/share/vim/` unless you are the administrator of a multi-user system and know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have enough space, you can copy whole /usr/share/vim/vim74 to your local directory and then set $VIMRUNTIME environment variable to this local directory.
Other way is to put `source $HOME/.vim/colors/scheme.vim` in your .vimrc .